# Using conditional in Terraform and GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-sql, service-accounts, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm working with a cloud sql module developed in my company. The module creates everything, this means the instance, database, Service Accounts, Firewalls, Private IP, Public IP, etc.

Our problem now is that every time we execute the module in and existing project we see in the logs the message that the Service Accounts already exists blahblahblah.
My main goal now is to clean up the logs and avoid this kind of message. I think to use count variable but I'm not sure if this will work (I've not tested it yet), because how can I get the name of the SA if terraform is executing? maybe using output variable? It's the same.
Just to see, this is an example of the SA we create:

```
resource "google_service_account" "in_ro" {
  account_id   = "in-ro-${var.instance_name}"
  project      = var.project_id
  display_name = "SA for Read Only Access"
  count        = var.instance_name == "" ? 1 : 0
}
```

Do you have any idea on how to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: This does not help answering the question at all. Where would you use the `google_service_account` resource? Are you referencing it somewhere else in the code? If so, you should add all the affected resource blocks.

Comment: Your module should have a naming standard of creating service accounts with account/project related information. You don't have much flexibility here & workarounds will make things worse over a period of time. Unused service accounts can be of great security concern as they are not managed, monitored & secrets are not rotated frequently.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that account_id  = "in-ro-${var.instance_name}" is not unique enough for the module to be reusable as it is right now.  Rather than checking if a resource was created by another process already, I would make sure that a new service account is created with each invocation and that it has a high likelyhood of not existing yet by using e.g. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs/resources/id.

Example:

```
resource "random_string" "random_suffix" {
  length  = 4
  upper   = false
  special = false
}

resource "google_service_account" "in_ro" {
  account_id   = "in-ro-${random_string.random_suffix.result}"
  project      = var.project_id
  display_name = "SA for Read Only Access (${random_string.random_suffix.result})"
}
```

Potentially lengthen suffix according to your module usage to project ratio, but keep in mind to stay within the 6 and 30 character limit for the entire account ID.

Comment: Great idea! appending a random (unique id) to the name should cover the case `Service Accounts already exists...`, to make this a better answer add a sample code that includes the original resource

Comment: Thanks!! I will test it and then I will came with the news. I'm sure it will work, crossing fingers!

Comment: @vpgcloud  I think the problem with this approach is that if I run more than once the same main.tf to modify something in the infra, it will create every Service Account because it's different from the first one. Am I right?

Comment: @DavidLinares, nope. It will be persisted in the state file, so it won't recreate everytime you run. But you will inherit other problems of piling up of unused service accounts.

Comment: Unused resources is a problem you face every time you don't destroy them correctly.